# iPhone No proxy set, However still connect to Internet

Tags: ios, iphone

Currently I have an app that needs to be able to work under a wi-fi environment with a proxy

Now I notice some apps do not require Http Proxy settings to be set 
(such as app store , itunes etc, though there are some non-apple apps out there too.)

I am wondering how they actually accomplish this?? As I would like my app to join this club

- Do they use WPAD somehow? (even then i never provide my proxy credentials)
- Do they use NSURLSession (I couldn't figure it out if it was)

I am using

```
NSURLConnection *_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delgate:self]
```

now this works fine when the proxy is set, and will ask for proxy authentication if needed.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!